# Determing a maximal ideal in $\mathbb{Z}_{12}[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Let $\mathbb{Z}_{12}[x]$ be the ring of polynomials in one variable over $\mathbb{Z}_{12}$.

How can i find a maximal ideal in $\mathbb{Z}_{12}[x]$?

I'd like to have a specific relation with the ideals contained in $\mathbb{Z}_{12}$, but I can not find it.

Comment: Hint. If $\mathfrak m$ is maximal ideal of ring $R$, then $R/{\mathfrak m}$ is field.

Comment: In light of NIghtflight's excellent hint: A) the characteristic must become a prime number in the quotient ring, B) the coset of $x$ must become either zero or invertible in the quotient ring.